# htaccess redirect from two domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have two domains, lets say `www.A.com` and `www.B.com` which are located on the same server. The directory is like this:

```
/html/index_of_A.php
/html/content_of_b/index_of_B.php
```

Now i want to configure an `.hataccess` file, which does the following things:

1) redirect users which enter `A.com` to `/html/index_of_A.php` (which is actually `www.A.com`) and
2) redirect users which enter `B.com` to `/html/content_of_b/index_of_B.php`

At the end, users enter two domain names (`a.com` and `b.com`) and they are getting redirected respectively to the specific folders of the domains.

Is that possible with htaccess?
The reason for this is, that i have two domain names, but they are on one server. Now I want to seperate both of them, to make "two different web pages".

Further, the users should always get rediretet to the `www` version.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that... I did some searches and tried different methods, but no success :(

Hope anybody can help me, appreciate that!

Comment: As a thought, why not place `A` in its own directory too? It appears that `B` is contained within `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly, there is no need to configure an .htaccess file.

You can solve your problem by slightly reorganizing your folder structure.

This is how I would solve it:

```
[folder for domain A/index.php]

[folder for domain B/index.php]

Configure your domain registration for www.A.com to point to [folder for domain A]

Configure your domain registration for www.B.com to point to [folder for domain B]
```

This way there is no need for an .htaccess file unless you are setting one up for security reasons (not redirection) AND you don't have to muddle through www.A.com's files when you need to focus on www.B.com.

I hope this helps.